# Отправка больших данных на сервер

Tags: php, c#, json

Требуется часто отправлять большой массив данных на сервер. На сервере стоит скрипт, который принимает данные в json и обрабатывает их (написан на php). На другом сервере стоит приложение на C# и формирует запросы. Из-за специфики БД (mysql) При отправке массива, состоящего из 2500 элементов, требуется отправлять 2500 запросов на обновление в БД. Естественно, хостерам это не нравится.

Запросы на обновление в БД выглядят так:

```
UPDATE `items` SET `".$Name."`=".(int)$Price[$i].", ".$Name."_date = '$datenow' WHERE `itemname`='".$arrItemsName[$i]."' LIMIT 1
```

Где:

```
$Price - массив с ценами
$arrItemsName - массив с названиями позиций.
$datenow - текущая дата. Вставляем в запрос закэшеированное значение, что бы не тратить ресурсы на выполнение NOW();
```

json данные, отправляются на сервер POST запросом и выглядят так:

```
{
    "alias":"ServiceName",
    "produtName": ["name1", "name2", ...],
    "productSumm": [5, 15, ...]
}
```

Может у кого-то есть предложения, как оптимизировать работу данного комплекса так, что бы хостер не страдал?

Comment: [Bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) жив?

Comment: А что значит, что хостеру не нравится, хостер страдает... Нафиг такого хостера тогда. Есть тарифный план. В рамках тарифного плана хостер предоставляет услугу. Вы ее используете на свое усмотрение. А что ему нравится или не нравится - это его проблемы. Если он не соблюдает то, что прописал в тарифном плане - меняйте его. Или хостер бесплатный, а Вы от него хотите невозможного? Или Вы купились на низкую стоимость тарифа и Вас не устраивает какчество услуг хостера?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете на клиенте формировать большой json-объект и разом отправлять его одним запросом, на стороне сервера Вам надо будет просто напросто парсить полученный объект и делать массовый update.